# Is there any way to recover my old password from android device using adb?

Tags: android, adb, backup

I recently had to format my device If there is a way possible to get the last password form my device as i need to restore the data from the google backup. It was a 4 digit (device)pin and everytime to try to cd it shows a error of `/system/bin/sh: cd/system: inaccessible or not found` I have the device with me and unlocked but there is no way to recover what ever the contacts and other things i had.

Comment: The Google password is never stored on your phone. It is sent only on first login to the Google servers and afterwards you get a random token that servers as password replacement. Even the Factory Reset Protection should not save your password but some salted hash of the password I would expect so it can not be reversed.

Comment: I wasn't talking about Google account password I was talking about the (forgotten)device password. That caused me to Reset. I did login with my Google account but the backup is asking for the last password (device pin) to restore.

Comment: Yes the backup is encrypted. I was confused by your question, especially by the part "everytime to try to cd...".That part doesn't fit into your question. I would strongly recommend to edit your question and improve it to make clear what you are actually trying. If you don't know the used PIN you can try to brute force the password, e.g. by writing a script for https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor (not sure if there are tools that allow to brute force an adb backup).

Answer (score 0):

Your backups are online, not on your phone.
See: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6305834?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

If the PIN you refer to was to unlock your device, this is not what you need. You need to log into your Google account (`<probably your name>@gmail.com`) and use the password for that account.

Comment: I am referring to the pin. I need the pin to restore my back up